# Pull-to-Refresh ListView in Qt/QML

Tags: qt, listview, qml, pull-to-refresh

Do you have any idea how to implement Pull-to-refresh ListView in Qt / QML ?

Answer (score 3):

Very simple solution present.
You must use "oncontentY". At that callback you can check Y coordinates when user pull list down. Select some value for ex: -250 (my case) when update request must start, and some Y value, that mean default position of content: -90 in my case, because i have header with height 90. Only one additional boolean variable must control singleshoot of update. This is all. And it worked.

Comment: This answer is 6 years late.